# How to query select statement with millions of input in text file

Tags: sql

I have millions of Id's in text file (temp.txt). I have to write a select statement which recursively execute by picking the ids from text file and return the output.

```
select * from table where id=123;
```

temp.txt

1234
1224
1232
.
.

Comment: I'm confused.  Normally, one writes `select` statements on data that is stored in databases in tables.  Are you asking how to connect a database to a text file?  How to load data from a text file into a database?  Or are we both confused?

Comment: @GordonLinoffI have those Ids in text file. I need to pass them through where clause . makes sense ?

Comment: Or does your text file have a list of IDs and you want to use those IDs to select date from a database?

Comment: @DStanley yes thats right.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Please pick the right tag.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

- Created a "linked server" using a text DB driver and join to your real data
- Load the text data to a temp table somehow and join that to your "real" data
- Use a script to generate a query with a massive "IN" clause (or multiple queries that are UNIONed together if the IN clause is too big)

Loading to a temp file is probably the most efficient overall, but may or may not be possible depending on your DB permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 5 IDs in your text file.. the IDs could be something like 1984, 2346, 2345, 6534, 1234.

To write a query to select all of these, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE column IN (1984, 2346, 2345, 6534, 1234);
```

For every ID in your text file, you need to put the ID with a comma after it inside the parenthesis.

This query selects all columns for each record in a table where any of the IDs you search for in the parenthesis match a column value based on the column you suggested in the query.